# CoffeeScript: simplest way to check if a function returns data

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a function like this:

```
getData = ->
  $('body').data('key')
```

I have another function that I want to use the first function to check if there's some data. What I *want* to write is this:

```
otherFunction = ->
  if getData()
    ...do something...
```

However, in my testing the statement `if function()` will always be true, because there's something there (a function). So the above doesn't work.

What's the cleanest way to do what I'm attempting here, check that a function returns some data?

Comment: `if fn()` and `if fn` are *not* the same. Check the assumptions about why the "if" is always true.

Comment: @pst, I'm pretty novice at JS, would you please elaborate or link to how they are different?

Comment: How does 1) call/invoke a function? and; 2) refer to a function-object (e.g. use as a callback)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. In my code or in general? Or are you being rhetorical? Like I said, JS newbie here :)

Comment: In JavaScript of CoffeeScript. They are the same in this regard (with slightly different syntax). I suggest starting with a tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern will definitely resolve to false (because of a falsy return value) if there is no data attribute, or there is an empty data attribute on a dom element.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wkGcW/1/

```
getData = ->
  $('div').data 'key'

getData2 = ->
  $('div').data 'foo', 'bar'

otherFunction = ->
  if getData()
    console.log 'yep'
  else
    console.log 'nope'  <--- Resolves false

  if getData2()
    console.log 'yep'   <--- Resolves true
  else
    console.log 'nope'

otherFunction()
```

You may have some other issue at play...

Comment: Yep, I see you're right. I've probably left of parens somewhere then...  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
if(getData() !== false) then do...
```

you would need to have a return escape on your getData method.

Is get data an object or a method returning data?

Comment: `getData` is a function call almost exactly like what I gave in the example, it looks up data attributes stored in the HTML. It's like an accessor method, I just use it to save tons of typing.

Comment: well it is somewhat prudent to know if the returned data from the function is boolean, or is it the value itself?

Comment: It is the value itself. That's the goal anyway.